# Annoying dock in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.04, 17.10, dock, gnome-shell-extension

today I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and the dock started to have really strange acting. First of all, I am a beginner in Linux. I am using Ubuntu GNOME and dash to dock extension, but after upgrade to 17.10 other dock started to appear even on locked screen:
[Dock on locked screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO5AC.jpg)

and also here: [Dock on password entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suvki.png)

and most annoying the dock is when I maximize app: [Dock on maximized apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix9rw.png)

I think it's the dock from old Unity GUI but I don't want to be there and I cannot find

1. settings for the dock to somehow disable/hide it
2. package name to uninstall it

Please help because I want to use old dash to dock extension

Thanks

Comment: do you have gnome-tweak-tools installed? you can actually see the docks  options there easily

Comment: I don't know what happened, but after third reboot it somehow magically disappeared

Comment: And yes, I have gnome-tweak-tool and I am not able to see dock options. I see only options from dash to dock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Uninstall Ubuntu Dock**

- Open the terminal and run these commands:

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
>
> $ rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
> ```

- Reboot.

**Install Dash to Dock**

- Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/ and install the extension by clicking on the On/Off button. You might need to install Firefox or Chrome GNOME extensions plugin

Comment: Actually uninstalling the `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` package uninstalls `ubuntu-desktop` too. This could cause problems. The dash-to-dock extension seems to be installable without uninstalling ubuntu-dock. Problem seems solved on my system running 19.04.