# Two docks on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Dash to dock extension, however, when I press super key the default Gnome shell dock shows on the left side alongside the Dash to dock's dock. Is there a way to disable this? I want to see only the Dash to dock's dock.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Related: [*How can I get rid of the dock in Ubuntu 18?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by removing Ubuntu dock extension.
This has helped me: [Annoying dock in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981503/annoying-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: I dont' think it's the solution: The following packages will be REMOVED:   gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: @lrkwz So far I haven't had any problems, it works fine.