# No app in ubuntu dock

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

Ubuntu 20.04, latest update.

I tried Gnome Extensions Dash to Dock, but it was not working well with the Ubuntu Dock (the ubuntu dock was spawning behind the dock) So I disabled it from the website. When I go to the Gnome extensions utility there's no more Dash to Dock extension, but if I go to the `built-in > Ubuntu Dock > Website` it open dash to dock github... So I think there's is something corrupted here...

Why do I explain all that ? Since then, I have to enable and disable the dock to see running app in the dock, if not there's only the app launcher icon.

Anybody ever experienced that ? Or anybody have a solution or a hint to fix that ? It's really annoying !

Update:

> I tried to remove dash-to-dock has stated here:
> [Annoying dock in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981503/annoying-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10)
>
> I rebooted the machine and now... No more dock! The Settings still
> have the option but no way to make it appear... So I re-installed
> dash-to-dock, still no option in settings, but I can configure it
> through dash-to-dock.
>
> It could have fixed the first problem that the original dock was
> spawning behind, but now there's no more default dock ! Oopsie!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My process was to install Dash to Dock (DTD) via FF, refresh FF, click on the tools icon and configure as desired.  To effectively disable Ubuntu Dock and have DTD work properly, I had to reboot, but then all was well and DTD appeared in the Extensions app.  I disabled Ubuntu Dock, but it doesn't seem to make a difference while DTD is enabled.